# Error compiling css file rails 4

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, sass

I recently bought a new theme for my website, I wanted to include the new file in the `application.css.sass`:

```
@import "custom.css.sass"
```

And I get this error :

```
Invalid CSS after "#ffffff": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ";"
  (in development/myapp/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.sass:142)
```

The css file is working just fine in it's own with html file, what do I do?

**Update**

Some css arround 142 :

```
.notification_error,
.notification_ok {
    background: #ffffff;
    border:#e6e6e6 1px solid;
}

.notification_error:after,
.notification_ok:after {
    background: #e6e6e6;
}

.shortcode_tab_item_title {
    border:#e6e6e6 1px solid;
}
```

Also if I import :
@import "custom.css"

All works just fine, however if I use just `.css` my assets are not loaded on heroku.

**UPDATE II: This is my Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.1'
# Use postgres
gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
# soft deleted
gem "paranoia", "~> 2.0"
# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
# background jobs
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
# rack options
gem 'rack-rewrite'
# static pages
gem 'high_voltage', '~> 2.2.1'
#haml templates
gem 'haml-rails', '~> 0.4'

#youtube like ids
gem 'hashids'

#better form
gem 'simple_form'

#password digest stuff
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.1.2', :require => 'bcrypt'

#aws stuff
gem 'aws-s3', :require => 'aws/s3'
gem 'aws-sdk'
gem 'fog'
gem 'carrierwave'

#assets
gem 'sprockets-rails', '~> 2.0.0', :require => 'sprockets/railtie'
gem 'asset_sync'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.2'
gem 'compass-rails',   '1.1.2'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

group :development do
  gem 'annotate'
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'foreman'
  gem 'rails_best_practices', '~> 1.14.0'
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'guard-livereload', require: false
  gem 'pry-byebug'
  gem 'spring'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.13.0'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '2.5.3'
  gem 'guard-spork', :github => 'guard/guard-spork'
  gem 'spork', '0.9.2'
  gem 'thin'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'awesome_print'
  gem 'sql_queries_count'
  gem 'debugger'
  gem 'oink'
end
```

This is my Gemfile, in case I was doing something wrong here because some stuff is taken out of the rails 4

Comment: well paste line 142 and maybe a couple of lines above and below

Comment: you can replace `background: #ffffff;` with `background-color: #ffffff;`

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady thanks for your response but I got the same error. I don't think something is wrong with the css file but rather the way how I'm setting up the app part that compiles it

Comment: It's probably a character that looks like whitespace but isn't.  Try validating it.

Comment: @cimmanon css file is valid with warning only according to csslint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is simply a difference between `.scss` and `.sass` syntax:

```
#scss
.notification_ok {
    background: #ffffff;
    border:#e6e6e6 1px solid;
}

#sass
.notification_ok
    background: #fff
    border: #e6e6e6 1px solid
```

As mentioned in another answer, just change the name from `custom.css.sass` to `custom.css.scss`

--

Further, you'll also want to just use the following:

```
@import "custom"
```

Answer (score 2):

The file you're trying to import is css, not sass. So rename the file to `custom.css.scss`. Also, you don't have to write the file extension in the `@import` directive, so change it to `@import "custom";` . Don't forget the semicolon at the end of the line, btw.